# Ideas on how to wrap tile around 45-degree wall corner

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile

We are putting in tile for a tub/shower surround. It is a pretty standard 5ft by 30 inch alcove. We tiled up to the edge of the front tub wall but now are not sure how we can wrap it around as the connecting wall is at a 45-degree angle. Everything we have seen appears to be designed for a 90 or a simple bull nose to end the tile.

Here is a picture showing the wall:
[image]

Comment: Isn't that a 135 degree corner?  I don't see why bull nose right to the edge wouldn't work.

Comment: *"We have to wrap because the tub is 30 inches so the tile would not expand past it."* Can you [edit] and rephrase that, because it makes no sense whatever to me as written...The answer by UnhandledExcepSean is exactly how I've dealt with making a corner where I could not buy corner tiles to suit (in that case, reusing 40+ year old tile so as not to have to retile the whole bathroom as matching what was there was not practically possible.)

Comment: Is there a reason your substrates don't butt up against each other?

Comment: That's a great question. It did not line up when putting the GoBoard in so we're going to pull the drywall and replace it, shiming if needed to make it line up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Miter the ends to match the angle desired would probably give you the best look. A wet saw would be my choice, but if you have a tile cutting disc for a grinder, that would work also.

Answer (score 0):

There are edge profiles not only for 90 but especially 135 degrees. Since the tiles are already in place the Miter Idea us out.

Comment: The tiles to be applied can be mitered to match the existing angles. While most of the time _both_ tiles are cut to matching angles, it's not required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! We are going to try to miter the one side first and if that doesn't work out will try some 135 degree edging.

Comment: only miter one edge will make it sharper and that tend to break and split easier in little corners. Also it is way harder to get the depth right, since one plane and the corner is already defined. What might also work for you is Pencil-tiles, their back is more often already mitered and since there are two resutling edges it gives way more wiggle room.